# LIKE %% multiples en PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` 
WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$bafle%' AND (`tags` LIKE '%$marca1%' 
OR `tags` LIKE '%$marca2%') AND `tags` LIKE '%$size%' 
AND `tags` LIKE '%$sistema%'";
```

en el cual intento seleccionar los resultados basados en criterios de búsqueda como por ejemplo: bafle/marca/tamaño/sistema, he logrado conseguir que me muestre los resultados pero con una marca, pero cuando intento mostrar los resultados con varias marcas me devuelve elementos que no he solicitado, en concreto creo que lo que intento decir es como hacer un filtro seleccionable estilo Ebay, pero que sea múltiple, en el cual podrás seleccionar mas de un filtro, agradezco la ayuda, saludos.

Comment: aclara bien con un ejemplo que tipo de búsqueda deseas realizar así como el resultado esperado pues tu pregunta es confusa

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiar tu operador logico.  En lugar de `AND` tienes que usar `OR`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` 
WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$bafle%' OR `tags` LIKE '%$marca1%' OR `tags` LIKE 
'%$marca2%' OR `tags` LIKE '%$size%' OR `tags` LIKE '%$sistema%'";
```

Comment: El problema es de que me devuelve todos los resultados y no los que le solicito, por ejemplo si selecciono marca A y B en el checkbox que he hecho en HTML te tendría que devolver Ay B como marcas, pero me devuelve A,B,C,D,E

Comment: Tienes los valores de marca, tamaño y sistema guardados en la misma columna `tags`?

Comment: no se que digas tu @alanfcm pero sería mejor que el OP agregue un ejemplo del resultado que espera obtener de la búsqueda y que lo explique mejor en su pregunta

Comment: Creo que si, @user3033258, seria bueno que agregaras la estructura de tu tabla, y mas contexto a tu codigo.

Comment: Efectivamente @alanfcm tengo los datos en una misma columna